# ruby array iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have four arrays(named array1,2,3,4) each with 8 objects and want to sort them into 8 empty arrays that will consist of 4 objects each, i.e place each object from array 1 into an empty array.

```
?? << array1.shift until array.empty?
```

I'm not sure how to iterate over the 8 empty arrays so that each of them recieves an object from array1

e.g

array1 = clubs1-8

array2 = spades1-8

array3 = hearts1-8

array4 = diamonds1-8

8 empty arrays or players, each player is dealt a card from array1,then 1 card from array2 etc.

Thanks for the answers but I wanted to add the objects iteratively so I could add conditions based on what objects had already been added to each array

e.g

distribute array1 among 8 empty arrays

distribute array2 among the 8 arrays but check before that no array contains the same card number (it can't have both the 2 of hearts and the 2 of diamonds)

Comment: Could you post a sample input and output?

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

```
require "matrix"

a1 = (0..7).to_a
a2 = (8..15).to_a
a3 = (16..23).to_a
a4 = (24..31).to_a

Matrix[a1, a2, a3, a4].transpose.to_a #=> [[0, 8, 16, 24], [1, 9, 17, 25], [2, 10, 18, 26], [3, 11, 19, 27], [4, 12, 20, 28], [5, 13, 21, 29], [6, 14, 22, 30], [7, 15, 23, 31]]
```

**Added:**

In fact it is even more trivial:

```
a1.zip(a2, a3, a4) #=> [[0, 8, 16, 24], [1, 9, 17, 25], [2, 10, 18, 26], [3, 11, 19, 27], [4, 12, 20, 28], [5, 13, 21, 29], [6, 14, 22, 30], [7, 15, 23, 31]]
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do this with arguments, choosing which element to add depending on which items are in the array, e.g for the card example - not having a card of the same n.o in each array

Answer (score 1):

Iteration is not the only way. Try this (assuming a1..a8 are your 8 empty arrays):

```
a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 = array1.zip(array2, array3, array4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):001:0> ar1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
irb(main):002:0> ar2 = [2,3,4,1,2,3,2,1]
=> [2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1]
irb(main):003:0> ar3 = [4,3,5,6,3,3,4,5]
=> [4, 3, 5, 6, 3, 3, 4, 5]
irb(main):004:0> ar4 = [5,2,5,6,7,2,2,5]
=> [5, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2, 2, 5]
irb(main):005:0> ar1.zip(ar2,ar3,ar4)
=> [[1, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 3, 2], [3, 4, 5, 5], [4, 1, 6, 6], [5, 2, 3, 7], [6, 3, 3, 2], [7, 2, 4, 2], [8, 1, 5, 5]]
```